# Having problems with ODEINT in python

Tags: scipy, differential-equations, nonlinear-functions, poisson, odeint

I am relatively new to Python and trying to use it to solve a second order nonlinear differential equation, specifically the Poisson-Boltzmann equation in an electrolyte.

```
phi''(r) + (2/r)*phi'(r) = (k^2)*sinh(phi(r))
```

Essentially it describes the decay of electrostatic potential (phi) away from a charged surface in an electrolyte with the rate of decay governed by a paramter k.

- phi(r) - the potential at r
- dphi(r) - derivative of potential at r
- r - distance from the surface (I am solving for r = 1 to r = R in this case)

and the boundary conditions

- phi(1) = 5
- dphi(R) = 0

The problem bit of code is as follows

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import root
from pylab import * # for plotting commands

k = 0.5 
phi = 5 
dphi = -10
R = 21

def deriv(z,r): # return derivatives of the array z   (where z = [phi, phi'])
    return np.array([
    (z[1]),
    ((k**2)*sinh(z[0]))-((2/r)*z[1])
    ])


result = odeint(deriv,np.array([phi,dphi]),np.linspace(1,R,1017), full_output = 1)
```

Generally for low values of k the integration works fine and I can use root from scipy.optimize to solve it subject to the boundary conditions, however when I try to use relatively large values of k (0.5 and higher) the integration runs into problems and outputs the following error

```
Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).
```

Having run it with full_output = 1 and had a look at the `tcur` parameter it seems to count up smoothly until a certain point and then oscillate wildly from very large to very small values. At the same point `nfe` the number of function evaluations drops to zero. When working correctly the tcur parameter runs smoothly from 1 to R. Could anyone enlighten me to why this is happening? Is it a problem with my implementation or is there an instability in the equation?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

The ODE is probably unstable. The related equation

```
phi''(r) = (k^2)*sinh(phi(r))
```

has a solution for `k=1` (for corresponding initial conditions at r=1):

```
phi(r) = 2 arctanh(sin(r))
```

The solution has a singularity at `r=pi/2`. A numerical ODE solver will not be able to integrate the equation beyond this point. It's plausible that a similar equation with the first-derivative term (which should be negligible close to singularities anyway) behaves similarly.

The actual problem that you have is that a shooting method using an ODE solver is not a good way to solve boundary value problems --- you should use collocation methods, which are fairly stable. See e.g. http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Boundary_value_problem and references therein.

For Python software, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=boundary+value+problem&submit=search

It's usually also very easy to write such solvers yourself, as the only needed step is discretization of the problem to a set of (many) equations, after which `root` can solve them.